# How to give rows in a bootstrap 4 container a total height equal to column height

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

If I have a container like so, how can I make the rows in the second column to stretch out their heights so that they match the height in the first column in total :

```
      <Container fluid>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            Only row in first column
            <img src="bigPhoto.png" />
          </Col>
          <Col >
            <Row>
                First row in second column
            </Row>
            <Row>
                Second row in second column
            </Row>
            <Row>
                Third row in second column
            </Row>
            <Row>
                Fourth row in second column
            </Row>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `display:flex` to the parent component.

```css
.parent{
  display:flex;
  border:1px solid red;
}

Row, Col {
  border: 2px solid black;
 }
```

```html
<Container fluid>
        <Row class="parent">
          <Col>
            Only row in first column
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/100/100/200" />
          </Col>
          <Col >
            <Row>
                First row in second column
            </Row>
            <Row>
                Second row in second column
            </Row>
            <Row>
                Third row in second column
            </Row>
            <Row>
                Fourth row in second column
            </Row>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
```

Comment: @user1511956 hope I have understood your issue correctly and resolved it. Please accept the solution if resolved. Please add a screenshot of the exact issue if you are still facing a problem,

Comment: I was thinking two columns with one row in the first column (that takes up a lot of height), and four rows in the second column, and not six columns. Does that makes sense ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following bootstrap class on the containing column.

```
 d-flex align-items-stretch
```

This would be the col that has the 4 items inside

Answer (score 0):

I ended up setting min-height: "height of image" / "number of rows" to get the effect I wanted in the second column. However, then it does not scale dynamically w.r.t the "height image" variable. I will try to check out answers from others and see if I can make that work in the meantime.